# switch place of a sentence to another sentence without changing a specific word place on notepad++

Tags: notepad++, reverse

i've searched alot for that but i couldn't find, switch place of a sentence to another sentence without changing a specific word place on notepad++

That means i want to change:

hello:imawesome |
yes:imawesome |
ohyeah:awesomevibes

i want to change it to:

imawesome:hello |
imawesome:yes |
awesomevibes:ohyeah

i hope you got what i mean i don't want to change the ":" place i just want to switch the texts places without doing any change in the ":"

on notepad++

i hope i find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you can make use of `([\S]+)` to find individual words, and simply seperate them by the colan `:` like so:

`([\S]+):([\S]+)`

And in the replace box just insert the following to reverse the order:

`\2:\1`

For input of:

`hello:imawesome | yes:imawesome | ohyeah:awesomevibes`

The result of replacing all instances is:

`imawesome:hello | imawesome:yes | awesomevibes:ohyeah`

Just make sure that the Regular expression option is ticked:
[image]